# Getting of entries of another column with criterias

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

Ok, so I'm trying to achieve the following:

List with names in column **N**

List with criteria (3 different words) in column **P**

Column F should now list all names of column **N** which do not have the criteria "No" in column **P**

I don't get the index function working correctly - either I get all names or only one name if I combine it with the match function.

How can I get that magic working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried a FILTER?

```
=FILTER(N:N,ISNA(Search("No",P:P)))
```

Answer (score 0):

try simply:

```
=FILTER(N:N, P:P="No")
```